# Difference between a REST API and a web application

Tags: rest

What is the difference when I am about to write a REST API?

I mean what considerations I should take into account which are not important for web applications?
including the server, programming style, tighter security considerations, etc..

Comment: Since when are REST api's not web applications?

Comment: They are some kind of web application, but it is rational that some additional principles should be taken into account for their design and implementation. Considerations that are not usually taken care about in regular web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be following RESTful principles as described in Roy Fielding document: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm

Answer (score 3):

To me, a web application implies a user interface -- HTML delivered from a server. A REST API, on the other hand, uses the HTTP protocol independent of presentation, and could equally support desktop clients, mobile clients, Flash/Flex clients, etc.